I’ve got a Pontiac G6 06 3.5v6 and the front brakes seem to stick and get tighter without touching the brake
I have Replaced the rotors, calipers, pads, abs modulator valve, and all 4 brake lines are fine and have no leaks, fluid come out strong and clear at the bleeder, and reservoir is in normal range. However my front left brake and sometimes the front right(like 20% of the time) will slowly start to tighten and won’t release without me hitting the brakes. I’ll just be cruising at like 40 and then I can feel my car start to slow down and I have to accelerate more to fight for the increasing drag. Which causes my steering wheel to shake a little almost like my rotors are warped but I checked them and they look fine but even so I still bought new ones and they looks straight as can be too but the issue persists. I thought maybe traction control, even off it persists. My only guess at this point is an ecu error or something idk, please help. Thank you

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Did you replaced the brake hoses? a Brake hose is a double type hose and the inner tube may be damaged. I would replace them before doing anything else.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
